Types from schema.graphql for the return type by SendQueryAsync
I am making a client in c# that will get data from a graphql endpoint. To know what I can get from the endpoint, I did an introspection with jetbrains grapqhl tool, and got a schema.grapqhl file describing the endpoint.
Now I want to use that to describe the result of a request. Is it possible to use the schema.graphql as a return type for a query?
I am using Graphql.client to build and send requests. I would like to do something like this:
var response = gqlClient.SendQueryAsync<EndpointResponse>(query)

Where EndpointResponse is typed by schema.graphql. Is that somehow possible?

I believe what you're looking for are GraphQL CodeGen, with its C# plugin.
These are the Node.js libraries that you can use to generate the files. These would be a script you'd run separately from your project to output the types that you could then consume in your project.

@graphql-codegen/cli
@graphql-codegen/c-sharp-operations

Notes:

The documentation for graphql-codegen is sometimes vague and assumes you're "in on the joke already", and I assume the documentation for this plugin will have similar issues.
I've never done this for C# types. I'm not completely sure this will get you what you want. I'm more familiar with this on the TypeScript side.

